# Do we know more about נבח?

Tags: historical-figures, mattos

The last verse of Parshas Mattos ([Bamidbar 32:42](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9960/jewish/Chapter-32.htm#v=42)) is about a fellow named Novach who conquered a city and named it after himself:

> וְנֹבַח הָלַךְ וַיִּלְכֹּד אֶת קְנָת וְאֶת בְּנֹתֶיהָ וַיִּקְרָא לָה נֹבַח בִּשְׁמוֹ

The Torah gives very little info about him.  In contrast to the two preceding accounts, we are not told his fathers name (or possibly his tribe).

Do we know anything else about Novach, and why does the Torah give so little information?

Comment: [Shoftim 8:11](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0708.htm#11)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Three entries in the Otzar Ishei Tanach. Novach was born in mitzrayim and died after Moshe rabbeinu, sedder olam rabba 9. When knas was captured, Novach called it by his own name, in order to have a memorial, being that he didn't have sons, medrash agadda bamidbar 32 38. That name didn't last, Rus rabba 5 5. 
Also of interest rav Hirsch discusses the unjewish act of trying to have a memorial by naming a city after himself whereas Judaism has good deeds for memorials. And that is why the name didn't last.

Comment: +1, but what's "the otzar"?

Comment: Sorry. Otsar ishei tanach. It brings down all the chazzal on any personalities in tanach. They have both hebrew and English versions.

Comment: No need to comment: just [edit] the post to clarify. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: I'm withholding accepting your answer on the hope that someone will explain why he gets such scarce attention at the end of Mattos.

Comment: user6591 About @msh210's comment -- see [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16529153#16529153)

Comment: @Yez- Honestly I'm surprised he got any mention. How often are individuals singled out in such fashion? If your main concern is why in parshas Mattos, I would simply say these are the parshios discussing the inheritance of the land. This is exactly where it belongs.

Comment: @user6591 no my question is, as stated, in contrast to those mentioned immediately before him who had their lineage listed.  He just gets his own name.

Comment: The vast majority of cities listed beforehand did not have their builder's names mentioned. All we have is which shevet built them. By Menasheh, the Torah has a different approach. It mentions the doings of the children of Machir ben Menasheh, and his Brother yair. And Novach. These are the chidushim. No children of Dan or Reuvein are mentioned in their conquests.

Comment: Turns out Yair was not his brother. Ramban and Ibn ezra bring from Divrei Hayamim that he was from shevet Yehuda but on his maternal side he was from.Menasheh. That leaves the door open to wonder what tribe Novach was really from. Also while reading the yichus in parshas Pinchas I am left with more questions. Maybe I'll ask them as a separate question.

Answer (score 7):

BS"D

Rav Eliyahu Mansour addresses this question in his 5766 (2006) derashah on Parashat Mattot ([link](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/WeeklyParasha.asp?ParashaClipID=109), starting at 45:55). He cites RaSh"Y ([BeMidbar 32:42](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9960/jewish/Chapter-32.htm#v=42&showrashi=true)) who points out that there should have been a mappiq in the *Heh* of the word "לה". And that, without the mappiq, the word can be read "לא" (i.e. "לא נבח"). Because it can be read as such, RaSh"Y explains, this can explain why Novahh's legacy didn't last. But, "what's the lesson" asks Rav Mansour?

Rav Mansour then cites Rav Shimon Schwab who explains that there is a big difference between Ya'ir and Novahh. The difference is in how two different people look at their wealth. Ya'ir had a proper understanding: wealth is not bad, but wealth does not define a person's essence. A person possesses wealth; but, that person's wealth does not define him. That, explains Rav Mansour, is why Ya'ir calls his cities Havot Ya'ir. Ya'ir is Ya'ir and his cities are his cities; but, they're not one and the same!

But, Novahh had a different philosophy: he called his property Novahh, because he saw himself as being defined by his wealth; as being one with his wealth. That is why RaSh"Y says it can be read "לא נבח". Novahh's legacy didn't last, because of his warped hashqafah.

Rav Mansour cites a common and unfortunate occurrence today. Today, we ask people immediately upon having a short conversation with them "What do you do for a living?" And, based on that answer, we judge them. If s/he is a doctor, s/he is respected. If s/he works in sanitation, s/he is a zero. We don't judge people for what they are, we judge them by what they have. The guy can be a crook and can beat up his wife. It doesn't matter. We're not judging the person based on those things. We're judging him based on his wealth.

So, by mentioning Novahh only briefly (thus implying that his legacy withered away), the Torah is teaching us the crucial and eternal lesson that "it's not what you have; it's what you are that matters".

Comment: I just realized that, explicitly, this only addresses the second part of the question (i.e. "why does the Torah give so little information"). Implicitly, though, I think it addresses the first part too (i.e. "do we know anything else about Novach").

Comment: Being that Rav Schwab quoted Rav Hirsch so often and the idea is the same, I would guess he is quoting him here too. But I don't have a Mayan Beis Hasho'eiva with me to check.

Comment: If YEZ prefers, our answers can be merged. Whatever makes the most sense.

Comment: +1 - is the last paragraph your addition/extrapolation, or also from R' Mansour?

Comment: The last sentence is my recap of Rav Mansour's derashah.

Comment: @Lee I recently had an opportunity to look in Rabbi Schwab's seffer and he in fact does not say this in the name of Rabbi Hirsch. Strange. But good thing we didn't combine answers.