# Midrash on Novach

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, midrash, shoftim--book-of, bamidbar-numbers-book-of, cities

In [Ruth Rabbah 5:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ruth_Rabbah.5.5?lang=bi) it says:

> "...And similarly "And Nobah went and took Kenath, and the villages thereof, and called it Nobah, after his own name (Numbers 32:42) this teaches that her own name did not remain to her..."

This is also brought by Rashi in the name of Rabbi Moshe Hadarshan in [Bamidbar 32:42](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.32.42?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.32.42.1&lang2=bi).

Yet the city Novach is mentioned in [Shoftim 8:11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Judges.8.11?lang=bi), hundreds of years after the capture of Kenat and its name-change to Novach. What, then, does the midrash mean that the name didn't remain to her?

Comment: Interestingly Rabbeinu Bachya also picks up on this grammatical structure and brings other examples - https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Bamidbar.32.42.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: Answer is potentially brought here - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/43679/22152 - i.e. the grammatical structure of the word alludes to the fact that this legacy did not endure. I guess a few hundred years is not a lot in the grand scheme of things :-)

Comment: @Dov Thanks, but it doesn't answer the question. Just to clarify, the question is not on the linguistics of the word לה in the verse, as presented by the midrash and R' Moshe, but on the city Novach itself and its history.

Comment: Apparently hundreds of years is not enough, at least compared to the other cities mentioned there.

Comment: @N.T. On the other hand, Chavot Yair, the only other place that's contrasted to Novach, is last mentioned in Shoftim 10:4 though highly unclear if it's referring to the same place or if it's even a place-name at all in that context. But even if it is, that's only a number of decades after Novach's last mention.

Comment: I'm assuming the Midrash's source was not in the Tanach itself but historical knowledge. The name Chavos Yair could have lasted much longer than that historically even if it is not mentioned in the text.

Comment: @N.T. Thank you, it seems you are correct: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%AA By the time of the writing of Divrei Hayamim, Kenat was back to being called Kenat, and this continued at least to the time of Josephus.

Comment: Er..I def made that point earlier :-)

Comment: @Dov Sorry, I still don't see that in the answer you linked. Certainly I understand that the midrash is saying that the name didn't last for certain reason, but I was asking based on what that is. Could you clarify?

Comment: Nope my throwaway comment - 'I guess a few hundred years is not a lot in the grand scheme of things'

Comment: @Dov Oh...sorry, I guess I missed that. I'll add you to my answer.

Comment: Lol no worries - I don't need the kavod :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Dov and @N.T. wrote in the comments, a couple of centuries isn't a long enough time to be considered having a lasting name, and there is indeed evidence that the name didn't last: In [Divrei Hayamim 1:2:23](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Chronicles.2.23?lang=bi) it says:

> "But Geshur and Aram took from them **Havvoth-jair**, **Kenath** and its dependencies, sixty towns. All these were the sons of Machir, the father of Gilead."

While Chavot Yair's name lasted until the time of Ezra and Nechemiah [who wrote Divrei Hayamim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Batra.15a.2-3?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi), Novach reverted back to Kenat.

Furthermore, Kenat is mentioned in [Yerushalmi Shvi'it 16a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jerusalem_Talmud_Shevi%27it.16a.1?vhe=Mechon_Mamre_Talmud_Yerushalmi&lang=bi) as one of the boundary-towns from the time of Shivat Tzion:

> "תחומי א"י כל שהחזיקו עולי בבל...וקנת ורפיח..."

Translation: "The boundaries of Eretz Yisrael - everything held by the people who came from Babylon...and Kenat and Rafiach..."

Finally, Josephus in Wars of the Jews [mentions a city called Kanatha](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2850/2850-h/2850-h.htm#link2HCH0019), which [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qanawat), can be identified with Kenat.

While Chavot Yair, the city compared and contrasted to Novach, on the other hand, is mentioned three more times after the time of Moshe: [Shoftim 10:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Judges.10.4?lang=bi), [Melachim 1:4:13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Kings.4.13?lang=bi) and [Divrei Hayamim 1:2:23](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Chronicles.2.23?lang=bi), with no name-change.

To conclude, the midrash is indeed correct that Novach's name did not last and at some point its name reverted back to Kenat.